# Parse iOS SDK: UIButton segue inside of PFTableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, segue

**Scenario** = I have a PFQueryTableViewController that is returning user's post objects. When a user clicks on a button titled "Comment" inside of each row for the post, the user will segue to another screen where they can post a comment.

**Things to note** = Inside each post object returned by the table is a key called "postID". It is this ID that I must "extract" from the row to query for in the next screen.

**Issues** = I am having trouble figuring out how to get the postID for each post.

If this was a simple row click I'd do

```
PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
```

And then just access the value for the "postID" key and pass that in the prepareForSegue. Butttttt...

**Question** = This is not a didSelectRowAtIndexPath kind of thing (or at least I don't think). This is a button click that is *on* a cell at an index path. So what do I do here?

Comment: You can add a tag to each button, ex. button.tag = indexPath.row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tag to each button that corresponds to its row, ex:

```
button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then give that button an action linked to a method which takes the button as a parameter, ex:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(goToCommentView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

So that when a button is selected, and the method is called, you can get the object using that tag, ex:

```
- (void)goToCommentView:(UIButton*)sender {

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndexPath:sender.tag];

    ...
}
```

Comment: I haven't even tried that yet but it makes so much sense Im going to mark it as answered anyways. Nice!

Comment: @TomTesticool Well, feel free to comment here underneath my post again if you have any issues with the actual implementation. :)

Comment: Well it seems I fudged something. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DashboardViewController commentButtonWasPushed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e58dd0'

Comment: What I'm wondering is maybe I placed something in the wrong place. Let me ask you if this was the right idea. 1) Does the button.tag = indexPath.row supposed to go in the VC's cellForRowAtIndexPath or the didSelectRowAtIndexPath? 2) Was the goToCommentView: method you made (mine's called commentButtonWasPushed:) supposed to go in the tableView's VC or the PFTableViewCell class for the cell?

Comment: @TomTesticool You should set the button tag within cellForRowAtIndexPath. And the commentButtonWasPushed method should go within the tableview's VC. From the error though it seems as if there's a problem with your commentButtonWasPushed call or method...as in the method called isn't equivalent to the method itself. What code are you using for the method call and what code are you using for the method?

Comment: You were exactly right. Thanks Lyndsey